# Undefined symbol trying to link XCTest target

Tags: swift, unit-testing, core-data, xctest

I am trying to test my application that uses Core Data. In order to test the my "save" method, I am using XCTNSNotificationExpectation for the notification NSManagedObjectContextDidSave, as shown below.

[image]

However, when I run it, I get the following errors.

[image]

I have other test files that test synchronous methods, which work perfectly if I comment this file, so I think the problem is with the notification or the expectation.

Could someone help me please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that it couldn't find the API `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` which belongs to Core Data

You have to import the framework

```
import CoreData
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I thought that if I had @testable import MyProjName, it would inherit the imports I made in my project..

Comment: Sadly, test targets don't automatically pick up framework dependencies from the system under test. This always catches me off guard.